# Error: v8@3.15 has been disabled because it depends on Python 2 to build

Tags: v8, apple-m1, apple-m2

I want to install v8 3.15 on MacOs with M2 pro apple chip. Getting the error that is disabled.

I tried to install x86-64 brew with rosetta and use that to install v8 but still getting the same error.
Does anyone have a work around for this, or homebrew has completely depricated v8@3.15 for both intel and apple chips?

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem for many, because at least therubyracer gem still depends on this version of libv8. It would be best to not use this old version by upgrading your application. If you absolutely have to, I found a way to install this using Rosetta 2 and homebrew.

Make sure you're using Rosetta and the x86_64 version of homebrew.

Install python 2:

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 2.7.18
pyenv global 2.7.18
```

Add pyenv to your path:

```
PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH
```

Try to install v8@3.15

```
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install v8@3.15
```

You will get the following error:

```
Error: v8@3.15 has been disabled because it depends on Python 2 to build
```

Edit the formula to enable installing the old version of v8:

```
brew edit v8@3.15
```

Remove this line:

```
disable! date: "2023-06-19", because: "depends on Python 2 to build"
```

Now you can install the v8@3.15:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew install v8@3.15
```

I believe this will work as long as the old formula is still available from homebrew.

Comment: hello. I get this error `arch: posix_spawnp: brew: Bad CPU type in executable` after running the last command